# No getter method for property: XXXX

Tags: jsp, struts-1

I am unable to find out what I am doing wrong

When i call my variable into JSP i have the error

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property: "gPClientCount" of bean: "informations"

JSP Page :

```
<TD width="40%" colspan="2" class="texteTableau2" align="left">
    <bean:write name="informations" property="gPClientCount"/>
</TD>
```

Getter and setter :

```
private String gPClientCount = "";
public String getGPClientCount() {
        return gPClientCount;
    }

public void setGPClientCount(String pGPClientCount) {
    gPClientCount = pGPClientCount;
}
```

Comment: Assuming your bean is resolved correctly, have you tried changing either the property attribute value to `GPClientCount` or (worse) the getter/setter to `getgPClientCount` and `setgPClientCount`?

Comment: I chage the the getter/setter to getgPClientCount and setgPClientCount and that work but i don't know why

Comment: Because Java is case-sensitive and the property is accessed through the getter/setter unless accessible.

Comment: I know that, but why getgPClientCount and not getGPClientCount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [Struts 2.3 to 2.5 migration - Fieldnames](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration#Struts2.3to2.5migration-Fieldnames)

> If you have field names which starts with single lower case letter,
>   for example: private String sTrng; public String getSTrng() {...}
>   public void setSTrng(String str) {...}
>
> change accessors to getsTrng and setsTrng.
>
> Or better yet, change field names to not contain single lower case
>   letter: private String strng; public String getStrng() {...} public
>   void setStrng(String str) {...}
>
> For additional info see WW-3909.